# make fail a github action when running pytest via a bash script

Tags: bash, unit-testing, github, pytest, github-actions

We run `pytest` using a bash script and need to fail a GitHub action based on the pytest exit code.

GitHub action

```
name: Setup Glue and run unit tests
run: |
chmod +x mycoverage
./mycoverage file_dir
```

Bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

coverage run -m pytest "$@"
coverage xml -i
```

We can get the exit code from `$?` and need to know how to make the GitHub action fail based on `$?` (non-zero values) in the bash script.

Comment: What you want is to check the command line output (of the script execution) to see of it contains a specific expression, did I understand correctly?

Comment: @GuiFalourd yes

Comment: In that case, I would recommend the following action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/assert-command-line-output (I've created it to check CLI outputs, but it can be used to check any command line output, even if it returns error, without breaking the Github Actions workflow). Let me know if it will be enough to resolve your issue.

Comment: If the `coverage` command exits with 1 if the tests fail, then adding `set -e` on the second line of your script should do the trick. The GitHub Action step fails if the script returns non-zero exit code already, so your problem is purely one of making sure the script exits correctly if any of the commands therein fail.